# Configuring both WSO2 IS and ESB in Linux box and facing errors while starting IS server

Tags: wso2

Here is a snippet of the exception:

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - Database may be already in use: "Locked by another process".
```

I am trying an example given in this url:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/2-legged+OAuth+for+Securing+a+RESTful+Service

steps:

1. copied both wso2 esb and wso2 is to linux box
2. started wso2 esb using ./wso2Server.sh --start. can access the management console.
3. trying to start wso2 is using ./wso2server.sh from IS_HOME/bin..And received this error.

Note: Still I can bring up the IS management console.

Comment: did you configure a port offset in one of the products? otherwise, ports will overlap and definitely there will be conflicts.

Comment: yes, I have already set an offset 2 for wso2 esb

Comment: wso2 esb is running on 9445 while IS is running on 9443